# Firebase Auth Logs - GCP

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is possible to retrieve the logs about when a user is log-in or log-out to the platform? And also send them to stackdriver as Cloud Functions logs?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is possible to retrieve the logs about when a user is log-in or log-out to the platform?

Unfortunately, Firebase does not provide such informations. To solve this, you should create your own mechanism to keep track of users log-in and log-out.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is Firebase Auth login at least rate limited to prevent brute force guessing of passwords?

Comment: @justColbs Yep it's still the case.

Comment: So could someone use Firebase Auth SDK to guess a password 1 million times?

Comment: To secure your database, you can use [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Answer (score 16):

**Update as of 03/27/2023**

[Activity Logging](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging#enabling_activity_logging) can **only** be enabled for "Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform" with a billing account attached and **can not** be enabled for "Firebase Authentication Legacy" (projects that haven't upgraded to Identity Platform). Those docs enable logging for the Identity Toolkit API (`identitytoolkit.googleapis.com`).

Once upgraded to "Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform" you can enable Activity logging via the REST API (instructions below) or via Firebase or GCP Cloud Console.

[image: Firebase Authentication Legacy Console]

[image: Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform]

"Firebase Authentication Legacy" projects were able to able to enable Activity Logging ***before 03/27/2023*** and that behavior will continue to persist, but new requests to enable Activity Logging will now fail.

**NOTE:** [Activity Logging](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging) that was enabled on a "Firebase Authentication Legacy" project ***before 03/27/2023*** will **not** enable Google Cloud Identity Platform for the project, so your project will continue to be subject to [Firebase Auth Billing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing#authentication) and not [Google Cloud Identity Platform Billing](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing).

---

One of the easier ways for you to retrieve the auth token for the REST
command is to have a project owner use
[OAuthPlayground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and authorize
the
*Identity Toolkit API v3 scopes*

[image: Identity Toolkit API v3 scopes]

After enabling Activity Logging you will be able to view [these logged operations](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging#logged_operations) in Google Cloud Logging. Now you will be able to see successful and unsuccessful login requests e.g. `SignInWithPassword` for email+password auth and `SignInWithIdp` for federated sign-in requests like Google SignIn. One way to view requests for a specific user you could filter the logs to only include a specific `jsonPayload.response.email`

One thing to be aware of is that if you have a large number of users, or really significant activity on your project, you might also want to [specify exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging#excluding_operations) to minimize cost/traffic/noise.

Comment: Thanks! Had trouble understanding where to get the auth token and your answer with screenshot was helpful.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful and should probably be part of the docs

Comment: where do I get the auth-token for the REST request to enable the logging?

Comment: After enabling the Identity ToolKit API v3 scopes in OAuthPlayground, hit the "Authorize APIs" button. That will bring up an OAuth consent screen, accept all that is presented. Then back in the OAuthPlayground UI you will be prompted to select the "Exchange authorization code for tokens" button in Step 2. After selecting the Step 2 dropdown will be populated with an access token that starts with `ya29.` copy that and use in the Identity Toolkit REST API call.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thank you - had already aborted a few attempts trying to figure this out. This answer really should be in the official docs!