# Getting FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/unknown] Everytime I click Register Button

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make complete registeration system for the flutter application. I am using flutter authentication and firestore database. When ever I click on 'Register Button' it show me the following error: `Exception has occurred. FirebaseAuthException ([firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Connection reset ])`

To be specific I think I am doing something wrong in this part of code (Full Signup function code is below):

```
void signup(BuildContext context) async {
final User = (await firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextController.text,
            password: passwordTextController.text)
        .catchError((errMsg) {
  if (errMsg.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    displayToastMessage("Email already registered.", context);
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
              animation = CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
              return ScaleTransition(
                scale: animation,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: child,
              );
            },
            pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
              return const Signup();
            }));
  } else if (errMsg.code == 'invalid-email') {
    displayToastMessage("Email Format is Invalid", context);
  } else {
    displayToastMessage("Error: $errMsg", context);
  }
}))
    .user;
```

The below code is the code which has to be execute whenever register button is pressed (Full Signup Code):

```
void signup(BuildContext context) async {
final User = (await firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextController.text,
            password: passwordTextController.text)
        .catchError((errMsg) {
  if (errMsg.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    displayToastMessage("Email already registered.", context);
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
            transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
              animation = CurvedAnimation(
                  parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
              return ScaleTransition(
                scale: animation,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: child,
              );
            },
            pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
              return const Signup();
            }));
  } else if (errMsg.code == 'invalid-email') {
    displayToastMessage("Email Format is Invalid", context);
  } else {
    displayToastMessage("Error: $errMsg", context);
  }
}))
    .user;

if (User != null) // user created
{
  print('Before ProgressBar');
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return ProgressBar(
          message: "Registering Please Wait..",
        );
      });

  //Save user information into Database
  await UserModel().addUser(
      email: emailTextController.text.trim(),
      name: nameTextController.text.trim());

  Navigator.push(
      context,
      PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime, child) {
            animation = CurvedAnimation(
                parent: animation, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
            return ScaleTransition(
              scale: animation,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: child,
            );
          },
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, animationTime) {
            return OTPScreen(
              passEmail: email,
            );
          }));
} else {
  // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
  displayToastMessage("New User account has not been Created.", context);
}
}
```

If needed I am ready to share my full code ro fix the issue, Please help me to solve this issue I had tried alot but failed everytime.
Thankyou!

Comment: Have you enabled logging? If so, can you share your logs? Also can you error code and messages as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException#FirebaseAuthException(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String):~:text=Check%20the%20error%20code%20and%20message%20for%20more%20details.)

Comment: @RoopaM I am not aware of Logging? It is new for me and I don't know how we can enable it and How it works.

Comment: Cloud Logging is a fully managed service that allows you to store, search, analyze, monitor, and alert on logging data and events from Google Cloud. For more details refer [cloud logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs#docs) docs. To enable logging check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/activity-logging#enabling_activity_logging) and this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637663/18265570)